# Different angular9 routes to apply class to nested html

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular9, angular-router

This is a challenge to incorporate Routing with HTML and CSS. I want two different routes, /layout1 and /layout2 to change my navigation link's text to Bold. The class "livemaps-bold" has that style. The below method of hiding one link and then and putting them into one containing div is all that has worked to get two different routes to affect anything in shared area simultaneously. I have tried many things and so far this is what has worked. It's important to understand that there are only TWO links, just there are multiple routes that affect the look of those two links.

Ideally, I could have done an OR for both routes in the same div- The first div works standard and as expected and is a good example. The second div is where I want to have the two different routes change the same link text. That is fine, both affect the containing div and it works, BUT, but it still only applies to the parent div.  And I need it to apply to the links.

Being creative, I can make some style changes to the parent div, but it's not the effect that I want.

```
        <div class="icon-builder"> <a mat-button  routerLink="/builder/builderdashboard" color="primary">
          <span  class="icon-titles" routerLinkActive="titles-bold><i class="fas fa-layer-plus"></i>  BUILDER</span></a>
        </div>

      <div routerLinkActive="livemaps-bold">
        <a routerLink="/livemaps/layout1"> <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i> LIVE PARK DATA</a>
        <a routerLink="/livemaps/layout2" style="display: none">Home</a>

      </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain in short ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a `routerLinkActive` on each `a` tag?

```
<div>
        <a routerLinkActive="class1 class2" routerLink="/livemaps/layout1"> <i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i> LIVE PARK DATA</a>
        <a routerLinkActive="class3 class4" routerLink="/livemaps/layout2" style="display: none">Home</a>

      </div>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, that doesn't work because the second link has to reference to the first, which has the link text that we want to show. All that is doing is hiding the second link.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just hiding and adjusting my style sheet. This wasn't my idea of ideal but since I'm much better at CSS it worked fine.

```
   <div routerLinkActive="livemaps-highlight-div" id="livemaps-square">
        <a routerLink="/livemaps/layout1">
          <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;LIVE PARK DATA</span></a>
        <a routerLink="/livemaps/layout2" style="display: none">Home</a>

      </div>
```